# Resizable container views containing view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I want to be able have several UIViewControllers on the screen at once, arranged as panes, as per the diagram below. 
With the ability to:

- add additional panes while the program is running.
- drag the bars between the panes to resize them

I was thinking of using container views (which are just view controllers?)

How would I best achieve this?

```
        ┌───────────────────┳────────────────────────────┐
        │                   ┃                            │
        │                   ┃                            │
        │                   ┃                            │
        │                   ┃                            │
        │                   ┃                            │
        │                   ┃                            │
        │                   ┃                            │
        │                   ┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
        │                   ┃                            │
        │                   ┃                            │
        │                   ┃                            │
        │                   ┃                            │
        │                   ┃                            │
        │                   ┃                            │
        ┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┫                            │
        │                   ┃                            │
        │                   ┃                            │
        │                   ┃                            │
        │                   ┃                            │
        │                   ┃                            │
        │                   ┃                            │
        │                   ┃                            │
        │                   ┃                            │
        └───────────────────┻────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have created a quick prototype to demonstrate how this can be done: https://github.com/MrNickBarker/iOSAccordionPanels/tree/master

[image]

I'll explain the essence here. You can check the details in the repo.

- All panels and separators are constrained trailing to leading to each other
- Separators are constrained to each other (trailing to leading) with the first separator being constrained to the leading side of the superview
- Each separator holds a reference to its constraint to the previous separator and updates that constraints constant with a pan gesture
- Panels have a minimum width constraint. Not strictly needed but looks nice.
- Separator constraints have a lower priority (for ex. 999) so that they respect the minimum width of panels which also gives a nice effect of panels growing back to their size if there is more room
- When adding or removing a panels remove the constraints and add them again for all panels and separators. This point can be improved to preserve the sizes of existing panels or animations.

Here is a crude diagram:

```
superview-panel-separator-panel-separator-panel-superview
superview-------separator-------separator
```

Comment: Great sample. I like this but I believe using constraints is possible thanks to the simple layout. this could be a lot more complicated for other layouts like tree maps etc. But for the purpose you show is great.

Comment: @Pauls it could get complicated depending what you are going for. In this case I didn't overthink it because this is what I understood the asker wanted to achieve.

Comment: thanks, i'll have a go at extending the code to include horizontal bars too

Comment: This looks pretty cool. Any chance you have since created a Swift version? 

Comment: @CliftonLabrum unfortunately no, but feel free to make a PR if you do it :)

Answer (score 4):

I would not use storyboard´s ContainerViewController. Those are more designed to be used on storyboards when you already know how many controllers need to be in the screen. You instead want to add remove controllers dynamically in code.

First implement a controller that handles plain views (panes). Put all your logic in there be able to add a pane, remove it and resize already in place views when a new pane is added/removed. I wouldn't use constraints either, is going to be too complicated. When you add a pane you would have to know what view's sides are surrounding it, grab them and add constraints to it. When removing a pane, you would have to remove also some constraint (not all) of certain panes..too much.

However if you use frames you can just build an equation that takes the width and height of the container and recalculates all view's frames.

Once you have that working, just add controllers into those panes (views) like:

```
//Here self would be the containerController and paneContainer one of the pane views
UIViewController *newPaneVC = [UIViewController new];
newPaneVC.view.frame = [self calculateFrameForNewPane];
[self.paneContainer addSubview:newPaneVC.view];
[self addChildViewController:newPaneVC];
[newPaneVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

//Add resizing masks to make sure new VC resizes with superview changes (example: when more panes are added/removed)
[newPaneVC.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

Lastly, take a look at this library:
https://github.com/yatsu/treemapkit

It was done 3 years ago but I used it in a project and worked well. It gives you all logic to draw views with different sizes on the screen based on an array of values. You add and remove panes with this and use the delegates to return cells (panes) with controller already added.

Comment: You say "I would not use containers" and then provide a code sample of using containers. I think you are misunderstanding what a container VC is.

Comment: Sorry I might have not explained that part correctly. I meant container as the one you see on storyboards. The one you drag to embed controllers into other controller in the storyboard. I will edit it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd setup each view + constraints in a separate xib and use Masonry for creating easy AutoLayouting constraints in code for the constraints between the views.

Comment: you can of course create multiple views in one xib  though

Answer (score 2):

I would have a ViewController that was responsible for managing and resizing the view controllers you would add.

Then, I would add view controllers and their views into that main view controller.

So, a couple of things you need to pay attention to:

- If you use auto-layout you need to add your views from view controllers with constraints, so when the size changes, the content of view changes as well.
- If you don't use auto layout you might want to do some changes when the size changes, and you can do that in the viewDidLayoutSubviews
- You can also use viewDidLayoutSubViews if you need to adjust sizes of tableviews/collectionviews

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution would be to create and manage UIViews that are in turn managed by a single ViewController. You could achieve the various sizes and tiled effect by using Auto Layout's aspect ratio tool for resizing. To create new tiles you could get a random number between a set interval to get different sizes.